# How to copy files to/from (gnome) desktop using Dolphin on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: gnome

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04 and I love it, however I prefer using the dolphin file manager from Kubuntu. I installed dolphin, but whenever I try to copy files to/from desktop, it doesn't work. It only offers "paste clipboard contents". I assume it's a linking issue between gnome and dolphin. Any ideas on how I can solve this issue?

With regards
Brenton

Answer (score 0):

This will not be easily solved. The implementation of the possibility of using your desktop to store files is very specific to the desktop environment. Currently, in Ubuntu, the functionality is not anymore provided by the file manager. It is now provided by a Gnome Shell extension.

Traditionally, and in many other desktop environments, that functionality is provided by the file manager itself. As such, Dolphin can manage the desktop in the KDE desktop, but not in Gnome Shell because the KDE desktop is fundamentally different. The file manager nemo manages the desktop in Cinnamon desktop, but would also still be able to do so in Gnome Shell, because it is forked technology.

Having this work would require programming to implement the functionality in one way or another, and thus is reserved to skilled developers.